# How can I implement a Functor trait in Rust?

Tags: rust, category-theory

I'm working through Category Theory for Programmers and one of its challenges is to implement a Functor interface.

[This](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/questions/2798/how-can-i-design-a-functor-trait-to-handle-trait) question provides the following solution:

```rust
pub trait Functor<A> {
    type With<B>: Functor<B>;
    fn map<B>(self, f: impl Fn(A) -> B) -> Self::With<B>;
}
```

However, this would allow `With` to be any type that implements functor. What I really want would be something like this:

```rust
pub trait Functor<A> {
    fn map<B>(self, f: impl Fn(A) -> B) -> Self<B>;
}
```

But `Self` does not accept type parameters. How can I get around this?

Comment: Monad, functor, and the alike, all have laws that should be respected, and which in Rust-like languages cannot be expressed as part of the type. Instead, you have to rely on documentation. As part of these specifications, you can also include the fact that `With<A> = Self`.

Comment: @jthulhu: _"and which in Rust-like languages cannot be expressed as part of the type"_ => Challenge accepted.

Comment: The functor laws are not required to be followed even in Haskell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As with another problem in computer science, by adding a level of indirection. That is, you can define a *family* of related types, then use that to enforce the appropriate constraint.

A family is, in the end, fairly trivial:

```rust
trait Family {
    type Member<T>;
}

trait FamilyMember<T> {
    type Of: Family<Member<T> = Self>;
}

struct VecFamily;

impl Family for VecFamily {
    type Member<T> = Vec<T>;
}

impl<T> FamilyMember<T> for Vec<T> {
    type Of = VecFamily;
}
```

And then you can leverage that with functors:

```rust
trait Functor<A>: FamilyMember<A> {
    fn map<B>(self, f: impl FnMut(A) -> B) -> <Self::Of as Family>::Member<B>;
}

impl<A> Functor<A> for Vec<A> {
    fn map<B>(self, f: impl FnMut(A) -> B) -> Vec<B> {
        self.into_iter().map(f).collect()
    }
}
```

It's a bit of mouthful... but [it does compile on stable](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=23b47db8ce43d7e4c752c57f7257f4a9)!